# Switch men and women' social position?

Tags: society, alternate-history

In my world, women always covered powerful roles since the beginning of the human species.

They were warriors, politicians, leaders, and the head of a family.

How should my world differ from ours to make this happen?

I'd like to exclude body alterations (for example, I don't want men to get pregnant).

Comment: You need to in some way make females more physically capable than males. Give them magical abilities, greater strength, agility, etc...

Comment: Hello. This falls under the ["Please develop my High-Concept"](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-please-develop-my-high-concept-questions) category of questions and as such gets my vote to close. The reason we do not allow such questions is because they are much too broad. Worldbuilding is for asking questions when you get **stuck on a problem** when building your world. But questions such as this instead (presumably inadvertent) ask us to do the job that you are supposed to do, that is to say: **build your world**.

Comment: @AngelPray No he does not.

Comment: @FezVrasta You need to start developing this concept on your own, and start building a world where the gender roles are swapped. And then — if you get stuck on a particular facet of this — you ask a question about that particular problem you are facing. But just saying "Here is the concept, now please build the world for me", no, that is much too broad and not in scope for this site.

Comment: @MichaelK If they seek to make females be the dominant sex, broadly across most societies and throughout time, than yes, they sort of do.

Comment: @AngelPray No. Dominance in human societies has nothing to do with physical strength.

Comment: @MichaelK Even in early societies (the ones that laid the groundwork for essentially all future cultural disparities between the sexes)? If so, I'd love to get a source backing up that claim so I can read more about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84721/discussion-between-michaelk-and-angelpray).

Comment: @MichaelK: *"Dominance in human societies has nothing to do with physical strength:" quotation sorely needed.

Comment: Relevant study: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chambri_people

Comment: @AngelPray Dominance in a 1 on 1 situation may have a fair bit to do with physical strength.  When you are running a society, you take great care to ensure you never find yourself in a 1 on 1 situation where physical strength matters.  It's an inefficient way to lead a people.  Consider that the most powerful people in the world may be men, but they are all older men who would be destroyed in a physical altercation.

Comment: @MichaelK how am I supposed to further develop my world if I'm stuck at this fundamental piece?

Comment: @FezVrasta Why even bother explaining it? You have a world, it is matriarchal... and if you do not know how it became matriarchal, then it is — obviously — not important for the narrative. If you — the author, with all your intents and plans for this world — do not know, then the details of **how** it came to be this way do not matter at all. Hence: Chekov's Gun applies: do not add details that do not matter. As far as exposition goes, you do not need more than the ["In a world..."](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InAWorld) intro, and then you are set.

Comment: @MichaelK I don't see this plan a good way to setup a strong foundation for a world building, all the social interactions are going to change, how can you describe any interaction between opposite sexes without an understanding of how they ended up there? Also, with you thinking we could as well close this SE site

Comment: @FezVrasta I have to say this: you are going about this in all the wrong ways. You are thinking that your world will drive the plot and the narrative. **That is not why people build worlds.** You build a world because 1) you want to make a **game** of some sort and need a setting for it or 2) you have a story you want to tell, and need a world as a backdrop to make the story work. You seem to have neither. You seem to have an idea that you want to swap genders about in the power structure, but you seem to have no idea **why** you want to do that. What is the purpose? Figure that out first.

Comment: A related question, what does it mean to you for women to hold powerful roles?  Do your women start acting like men, or is the entire world rewritten from the ground up to have the power held by people who act differently than those who hold power today?

Comment: @CortAmmon the question explicitly states I want it to start from the beginning of the species

Comment: @FezVrasta Right, but *how* do you want that to happen?  What do you want the culture to look like?  Is it nothing more than "exactly the culture we have today, except the women wear the pants," or do you have a culture which is substantially different from human cultures?  Those two paths yield starkly different world.

Comment: @CortAmmon ideally it should require less modifications from your world as possible

Comment: @CortAmmon As discussed in this [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84721/discussion-between-michaelk-and-angelpray), that is not what I meant. What I did mean is that within the earliest societies that set the precedence for future cultural male dominance, might makes right was the rule of the day. Obviously, that is no longer the case, but the precedence that led to our current patriarchal societies still remains. I should have expanded on _why_ I said females had to be given an advantage over males, but I didn't, and both you and MichaelK thought I meant something patently absurd.

Answer (score 1):

This is not easy. In an era of muscle-powered weapons, the upper body strength and generally larger size of men counts for much.

- Introduce a safe and reliable natural (herbal?) contraceptive. This would give women other choices than abstinence to schedule childbirth.
- Other medications and medical procedures to reduce the death rate of mothers and children.

The net result is that women spend perhaps two or three years of their live in late pregnancy or with little babies to assure a modest population growth.

Look for ways to discourage hand-to-hand combat. That will be difficult, of course.

- Light horses with horse archers instead of large horses with lancers?
- Naval combat instead of land combat?

Comment: *"Light [cavalry]":* in the antiquity cavalry was much less important than infantry; lack of stirrups made it diffucult to control the horse and fight at the same time. *"Naval combat:"* with *women* rowing the ships?

Comment: @AlexP, make horses more common but not stirrups (those lead to lances), and women rowers will have it easier than women in a phalanx.

Comment: *"Women rowers will have it easier than women in a phalanx"* ... until they meet a navy with male rowers. I foresee great disconfiture. There is a reason why mixed sex rowing competitions are not a thing.

Comment: @AlexP, I'm talking about comparative advantage. What forms of warfare would you suggest where women are *less* disadvantaged?

Comment: In a world with pre-modern technology? There isn't. In pre-modern societies women are *precious* and irreplaceable. During the second Punic War, the Romans lost over 300,000 men of military age; losing a similar number of fertile women would have put an early end to the Roman society.

Comment: @AlexP, hence the first part of my answer re health and reproduction.